# Why does Horagalles have a nail on his head?

Tags: sami

According to Wikipedia, the Sami thunder god Horagalles was depicted with a nail or spike on the head:

> Idols of Horagalles are made of wood and have a nail or spike and a piece of flint in the head. He has a hammer called Wetschera, Aijeke Wetschera, or Ajeke veċċera, "grandfather's hammer."
>
> <sub>Horagalles. (2016, October 3). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 09:02, February 28, 2017, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Horagalles&oldid=742335950</sub>

Why is that? What is the story of this unique feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may relate to some feature in Finnish cosmology, but one possible answer is may come by way of the Scandinavian god Thor. Horgalles' name is sometimes explained as a form of Thor karl, Old Man Thor, and he may have borrowed his nail from Thor's cult as well.
There are two references to god-nails, [reginnaglar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginnaglar), in Scandinavian literature, one of which might explain Horgalles' nail:

> Thereafter Thorolf fared with fire through his land out from
>   Staff-river in the west, and east to that river which is now called
>   Thors-river, and settled his shipmates there. But he set up for
>   himself a great house at Templewick which he called Templestead. There
>   he let build a temple, and a mighty house it was. There was a door in
>   the side-wall and nearer to one end thereof. Within the door stood the
>   pillars of the high-seat, and nails were therein; they were called the
>   Gods' nails. ([*Eyrbyggja saga*](http://sagadb.org/eyrbyggja_saga.en))

One of the [pillars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96ndvegiss%C3%BAlur) was carved with an image of Thor, by the way, just to tie it up. Some scholars, such H.R.E. Davidson, connect the god-nails with they myth of how Thor got a [whetstone embedded](https://norse-mythology.org/tales/thors-duel-with-hrungnir/) in his forehead while fighting a giant. (Gods and Myths of the Ancient Northmen: 78) She also suggests that the nails were used to strike sparks for fire in the temples. She quotes a late saga, *Kjalnesinga saga*, as saying that Thor's temple had a fire that was never allowed to go out. (Follow [this link](http://odin.heathenthing.org/?page_id=97) to learn more about needfires and how to start them.)